# Power BI report template

Tags: report, powerbi

Today I have to create many reports based on many country's datasets which have the same structure (population, GDP, unemployment rating... by the year).

So how can I create a report template for the first country and apply it for the other one. What I expect is only by changing the country's dataset then we have a new report automatically.

Does PowerBI service or Desktop support it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you might be looking for was released with the April release of power bi desktop.

Please see [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-april-update-feature-summary/) look for "POWER BI TEMPLATE FILES"

> Exporting Power BI  content as a template is another new feature that will help streamline work. Power BI templates (.pbit files) include the definition of a Report, Data Model and queries, but not the actual data. Templates can be created via File -> Export -> Power BI Template, which generates a .pbit file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it worked but today I found that everything is very easy in simple way. I merge all datasets into one. So I create a report with a slicer based on Country then have all report only by filtering on slicer :)